# Page loading indicator

Tags: load-time

I have a page, and it takes a few seconds to load. I know, and I will make the site load faster (and not the question), but due to animations animating the site in, I am thinking of adding a page loading indicator.

This will be injected trough JavaScript and removed again by JavaScript, and removed trough JavaScript, making a non JavaScript page work as normal.

Is this a good or bad practice to add a page loader indicator on a standard HTML/CSS based site?

Answer (score 2):

Of course it's better to trying to avoid JavaScript, but in this case, if your JavaScript isn't that big + it's useful, I don't see any harm in it.

Answer (score 2):

It is a good practice when you certainly know that loading time is more then 1-1.5 seconds. So, according to this:

> I know, and I will make the site load faster

it's up to you. Maybe it's good idea to add the indicator before you implement some performance changes. 
Anyway, a neat and nice looking/working indicator is a good way to show users you're carrying about them.